# Global symbol doesn't recognized on perl

Tags: perl, system

I am getting an error because Global symbol doesn't take. please help me on this matter.

Error Message :

In the string, @@g now must be written as \@g at gsx.pl line 5, near "echo Ra@@@g"
Global symbol "@@g" requires explicit package name at ggg.pl line 5.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "connect to Perforce Server\n";
my $connection=`echo Ra@@@g|p4 -u raj login`;
if ( !$connection ) {
    print "Failed to connect to Perforce Server\n";
    exit(1);
}

my $status = system("p4 sync");
if ($status == 0) {
    my $workon = system("workon demo_project");
    my $build = system("gmake –f Makefile bin");         
} else {
    exit 1;
}
```

Comment: What Perl version do you have? I'm getting totally different error, and a nice warning, too, in 5.18.2: `Possible unintended interpolation of @g in string at ....
Global symbol "@g" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @g"?)`

Comment: This is perl, v5.6.0 built for sun4-solaris

Comment: It's working now after put in to backslash `echo Ra@@\@g | p4 -u raj login`;

Comment: 5.6.0 is 18 years old!

Comment: I've edited your code to fix the indentation. you're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Sensible indentation is one of the best ways to make your code easy to understand. If you're asking a large group of people to read and understand your code, it's a good idea to make that as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@g` is interpreted as the `@g` array, as backquotes interpolate variables including arrays.

Moreover, the error message has been changed years ago, it seems your Perl version is very old. Consider upgrading it.

To use `@g` as a string in backquotes, you need to escape the at-sign:

```
my $connection = `echo Ra@@\@g | p4 -u raj login`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Comment: oh, weird. Comment retracted. `@@` doesn't get interpolated somehow. I'd still escape them than relying on that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

what you would like to achieve with this:

```
echo Ra@@@g
```

what about using:

```
my $tmp = 'Ra@@@g';
my $connection=`echo $tmp|p4 -u raj login`;
```

Comment: That will still fail if the password contains spaces, parens, etc

Answer (score 0):

`` qx`...` `` aka `` `...` `` interpolates like double-quoted strings (`qq"..."` aka `"..."`).

```
my $connection = `echo Ra\@\@\@g | p4 -u raj login`;
```

Ideally, though, the password would be a separate variable.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $password = 'Ra@@@g';

my $cmd1 = shell_quote("printf", "%s", $password);
my $cmd2 = shell_quote("p4", "-u", "raj", "login");

my $connection = `$cmd1 | $cmd2`;
```